# Next.js getServerSideProps return undefined after deploy in vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am building a Netflix clone with next.js.
I can get the movie data from TMDB with getServerSideProps().
It works fine in dev mode but after deploy in vercel (re-deployed multiple times), the props I get from getServerSideProps() are undefined. What did I do wrong?

My Home page:

```
const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ netflixOriginals }) => {
  console.log({
    netflixOriginals,
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Banner netflixOriginals={netflixOriginals} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is getServerSideProps():

```
import requests from "../utils/request";

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      netflixOriginals: data.results,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
};
```

/utils/request:

```
const API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY;
const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";

export const IMG_SRC_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: `${BASE_URL}/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  fetchNetflixOriginals: `${BASE_URL}/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_networks=213`,
};

export default requests;
```

My Home page in localhost:
[image]

Console.log in dev mode:

```
{
  netflixOriginals: [
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/nmGWzTLMXy9x7mKd8NKPLmHtWGa.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            10751,
            16,
            12,
            35,
            14
        ],
        "id": 438148,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Minions: The Rise of Gru",
        "overview": "A fanboy of a supervillain supergroup known as the Vicious 6, Gru hatches a plan to become evil enough to join them, with the backup of his followers, the Minions.",
        "popularity": 11087.461,
        "poster_path": "/wKiOkZTN9lUUUNZLmtnwubZYONg.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-29",
        "title": "Minions: The Rise of Gru",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.6,
        "vote_count": 333
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/wcKFYIiVDvRURrzglV9kGu7fpfY.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            14,
            28,
            12
        ],
        "id": 453395,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness",
        "overview": "Doctor Strange, with the help of mystical allies both old and new, traverses the mind-bending and dangerous alternate realities of the Multiverse to confront a mysterious new adversary.",
        "popularity": 4341.28,
        "poster_path": "/9Gtg2DzBhmYamXBS1hKAhiwbBKS.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-05-04",
        "title": "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.5,
        "vote_count": 4415
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/p1F51Lvj3sMopG948F5HsBbl43C.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            14
        ],
        "id": 616037,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
        "overview": "After his retirement is interrupted by Gorr the God Butcher, a galactic killer who seeks the extinction of the gods, Thor enlists the help of King Valkyrie, Korg, and ex-girlfriend Jane Foster, who now inexplicably wields Mjolnir as the Mighty Thor. Together they embark upon a harrowing cosmic adventure to uncover the mystery of the God Butcher’s vengeance and stop him before it’s too late.",
        "popularity": 3675.753,
        "poster_path": "/pIkRyD18kl4FhoCNQuWxWu5cBLM.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-07-06",
        "title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.9,
        "vote_count": 791
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/393mh1AJ0GYWVD7Hsq5KkFaTAoT.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            12,
            28,
            878
        ],
        "id": 507086,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Jurassic World Dominion",
        "overview": "Four years after Isla Nublar was destroyed, dinosaurs now live—and hunt—alongside humans all over the world. This fragile balance will reshape the future and determine, once and for all, whether human beings are to remain the apex predators on a planet they now share with history’s most fearsome creatures.",
        "popularity": 3190.202,
        "poster_path": "/kAVRgw7GgK1CfYEJq8ME6EvRIgU.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-01",
        "title": "Jurassic World Dominion",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.6,
        "vote_count": 1169
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/tqUD26YGjKmFqOJAgbNBah1gX0N.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            16,
            878,
            12,
            28,
            10751
        ],
        "id": 718789,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Lightyear",
        "overview": "Legendary Space Ranger Buzz Lightyear embarks on an intergalactic adventure alongside a group of ambitious recruits and his robot companion Sox.",
        "popularity": 2710.323,
        "poster_path": "/vpILbP9eOQEtdQgl4vgjZUNY07r.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-15",
        "title": "Lightyear",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7,
        "vote_count": 460
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/AaV1YIdWKnjAIAOe8UUKBFm327v.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            18
        ],
        "id": 361743,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Top Gun: Maverick",
        "overview": "After more than thirty years of service as one of the Navy’s top aviators, and dodging the advancement in rank that would ground him, Pete “Maverick” Mitchell finds himself training a detachment of TOP GUN graduates for a specialized mission the likes of which no living pilot has ever seen.",
        "popularity": 3658.809,
        "poster_path": "/62HCnUTziyWcpDaBO2i1DX17ljH.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-05-24",
        "title": "Top Gun: Maverick",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8.4,
        "vote_count": 1556
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/5PnypKiSj2efSPqThNjTXz8jwOg.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            14,
            28
        ],
        "id": 759175,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Princess",
        "overview": "A beautiful, strong-willed young royal refuses to wed the cruel sociopath to whom she is betrothed and is kidnapped and locked in a remote tower of her father’s castle. With her scorned, vindictive suitor intent on taking her father’s throne, the princess must protect her family and save the kingdom.",
        "popularity": 2126.827,
        "poster_path": "/gt9s8TtZZ36TXF1CE1y19rSpOZu.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-16",
        "title": "The Princess",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.5,
        "vote_count": 107
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/ta17TltHGdZ5PZz6oUD3N5BRurb.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            53
        ],
        "id": 924482,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Ledge",
        "overview": "A rock climbing adventure between two friends turns into a terrifying nightmare. After Kelly captures the murder of her best friend on camera, she becomes the next target of a tight-knit group of friends who will stop at nothing to destroy the evidence and anyone in their way. Desperate for her safety, she begins a treacherous climb up a mountain cliff and her survival instincts are put to the test when she becomes trapped with the killers just 20 feet away.",
        "popularity": 1930.277,
        "poster_path": "/dHKfsdNcEPw7YIWFPIhqiuWrSAb.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-02-18",
        "title": "The Ledge",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.5,
        "vote_count": 46
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/egoyMDLqCxzjnSrWOz50uLlJWmD.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            10751,
            35
        ],
        "id": 675353,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Sonic the Hedgehog 2",
        "overview": "After settling in Green Hills, Sonic is eager to prove he has what it takes to be a true hero. His test comes when Dr. Robotnik returns, this time with a new partner, Knuckles, in search for an emerald that has the power to destroy civilizations. Sonic teams up with his own sidekick, Tails, and together they embark on a globe-trotting journey to find the emerald before it falls into the wrong hands.",
        "popularity": 1784.175,
        "poster_path": "/6DrHO1jr3qVrViUO6s6kFiAGM7.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-03-30",
        "title": "Sonic the Hedgehog 2",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.7,
        "vote_count": 2460
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/zGLHX92Gk96O1DJvLil7ObJTbaL.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            14,
            12,
            28
        ],
        "id": 338953,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore",
        "overview": "Professor Albus Dumbledore knows the powerful, dark wizard Gellert Grindelwald is moving to seize control of the wizarding world. Unable to stop him alone, he entrusts magizoologist Newt Scamander to lead an intrepid team of wizards and witches. They soon encounter an array of old and new beasts as they clash with Grindelwald's growing legion of followers.",
        "popularity": 1622.648,
        "poster_path": "/8ZbybiGYe8XM4WGmGlhF0ec5R7u.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-04-06",
        "title": "Fantastic Beasts: The Secrets of Dumbledore",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.8,
        "vote_count": 2233
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/ocUp7DJBIc8VJgLEw1prcyK1dYv.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            878
        ],
        "id": 634649,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
        "overview": "Peter Parker is unmasked and no longer able to separate his normal life from the high-stakes of being a super-hero. When he asks for help from Doctor Strange the stakes become even more dangerous, forcing him to discover what it truly means to be Spider-Man.",
        "popularity": 1602.44,
        "poster_path": "/1g0dhYtq4irTY1GPXvft6k4YLjm.jpg",
        "release_date": "2021-12-15",
        "title": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8.1,
        "vote_count": 14090
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/tsC3DRGAQvkoA88lQQfbQ40byFS.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            27,
            53
        ],
        "id": 756999,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Black Phone",
        "overview": "Finney Shaw, a shy but clever 13-year-old boy, is abducted by a sadistic killer and trapped in a soundproof basement where screaming is of little use. When a disconnected phone on the wall begins to ring, Finney discovers that he can hear the voices of the killer’s previous victims. And they are dead set on making sure that what happened to them doesn’t happen to Finney.",
        "popularity": 1522.809,
        "poster_path": "/wd6WxLLR2w8aAXmLPDW5CN0iSB3.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-22",
        "title": "The Black Phone",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.4,
        "vote_count": 349
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/t0mwKhUDa62hdhdKSsN4xMfhY5Z.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            18,
            35
        ],
        "id": 626735,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Dog",
        "overview": "An army ranger and his dog embark on a road trip along the Pacific Coast Highway to attend a friend's funeral.",
        "popularity": 1496.998,
        "poster_path": "/rkpLvPDe0ZE62buUS32exdNr7zD.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-02-17",
        "title": "Dog",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.4,
        "vote_count": 601
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/1Ds7xy7ILo8u2WWxdnkJth1jQVT.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            35
        ],
        "id": 752623,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Lost City",
        "overview": "A reclusive romance novelist was sure nothing could be worse than getting stuck on a book tour with her cover model until a kidnapping attempt sweeps them both into a cutthroat jungle adventure, proving life can be so much stranger, and more romantic, than any of her paperback fictions.",
        "popularity": 1421.055,
        "poster_path": "/neMZH82Stu91d3iqvLdNQfqPPyl.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-03-24",
        "title": "The Lost City",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.8,
        "vote_count": 1482
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/uR0FopHrAjDlG5q6PZB07a1JOva.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            16,
            878,
            28
        ],
        "id": 610150,
        "original_language": "ja",
        "original_title": "ドラゴンボール超：スーパーヒーロー",
        "overview": "The Red Ribbon Army, an evil organization that was once destroyed by Goku in the past, has been reformed by a group of people who have created new and mightier Androids, Gamma 1 and Gamma 2, and seek vengeance against Goku and his family.",
        "popularity": 1312.175,
        "poster_path": "/rugyJdeoJm7cSJL1q4jBpTNbxyU.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-11",
        "title": "Dragon Ball Super: Super Hero",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 8,
        "vote_count": 69
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/v7hdWmLh6VLgZQgkbHDxAa17M47.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            80,
            53
        ],
        "id": 852592,
        "original_language": "es",
        "original_title": "Centauro",
        "overview": "Rafa's hooked on the pure, fiery feelings he gets from speed racing, but when his kid's mom gets mixed up with drug dealers, he burns rubber to save her.",
        "popularity": 1309.498,
        "poster_path": "/wOx97MJOxEoR38aoya3lopyrlYC.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-15",
        "title": "Centauro",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.5,
        "vote_count": 65
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/gG9fTyDL03fiKnOpf2tr01sncnt.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            878,
            14
        ],
        "id": 526896,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "Morbius",
        "overview": "Dangerously ill with a rare blood disorder, and determined to save others suffering his same fate, Dr. Michael Morbius attempts a desperate gamble. What at first appears to be a radical success soon reveals itself to be a remedy potentially worse than the disease.",
        "popularity": 1264.722,
        "poster_path": "/6JjfSchsU6daXk2AKX8EEBjO3Fm.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-03-30",
        "title": "Morbius",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.4,
        "vote_count": 2037
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/iOFBH9KtjKMntbP2kheeOpMQTcC.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            35,
            53
        ],
        "id": 667739,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Man from Toronto",
        "overview": "In a case of mistaken identity, the world’s deadliest assassin, known as the Man from Toronto, and a New York City screw-up are forced to team up after being confused for each other at an Airbnb.",
        "popularity": 1214.243,
        "poster_path": "/uTCfTibqtk4f90cC59bLPMOmsfc.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-06-24",
        "title": "The Man from Toronto",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 6.2,
        "vote_count": 328
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/t9K8ycUBCplWiICDOKRNRYcEH9e.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            16,
            28,
            14
        ],
        "id": 810693,
        "original_language": "ja",
        "original_title": "劇場版 呪術廻戦 0",
        "overview": "Yuta Okkotsu is a nervous high school student who is suffering from a serious problem—his childhood friend Rika has turned into a curse and won't leave him alone. Since Rika is no ordinary curse, his plight is noticed by Satoru Gojo, a teacher at Jujutsu High, a school where fledgling exorcists learn how to combat curses. Gojo convinces Yuta to enroll, but can he learn enough in time to confront the curse that haunts him?",
        "popularity": 1148.276,
        "poster_path": "/3pTwMUEavTzVOh6yLN0aEwR7uSy.jpg",
        "release_date": "2021-12-24",
        "title": "Jujutsu Kaisen 0",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.9,
        "vote_count": 215
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/fqw8nJLPRgKRyFSDC0xBsC06NGC.jpg",
        "genre_ids": [
            28,
            12,
            14
        ],
        "id": 639933,
        "original_language": "en",
        "original_title": "The Northman",
        "overview": "Prince Amleth is on the verge of becoming a man when his father is brutally murdered by his uncle, who kidnaps the boy's mother. Two decades later, Amleth is now a Viking who's on a mission to save his mother, kill his uncle and avenge his father.",
        "popularity": 1133.955,
        "poster_path": "/8p9zXB7M78nZpm215zHfqpknMeM.jpg",
        "release_date": "2022-04-07",
        "title": "The Northman",
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.2,
        "vote_count": 1843
    }
]}
```

My Home page after deploy to vercel:
[image]

console.log in deploy:

```
{
  netflixOriginals: undefined
}
```

Comment: Did you define your `env` variables in vercel?

Comment: Oh... I feel so dumb. It works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to debug the fetch request and post what it returns. That's where the error is coming from.